# how to hide the hover text when my mouse does not move over the specified button

Tags: java, button, netbeans, hover

I have some buttons and a combo box i wanted to display some text when my mouse moves on the buttons. I used a text box to display the text. I used Mouse Motion event in that Mouse moved.It is working fine. But my question is i wanted to display the text only when i move my mouse over that button otherwise it should hide and should not display any message. But i am not able to do it.

```
 private void jComboBox2MouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
 jTextField1.setText("Select the value");
}                                     

private void jButton1MouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
    jTextField1.setText("Press the connect button");
}                                   

private void jButton6MouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
     jTextField1.setText("Press to exit");
}                                   

private void jButton7MouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
     jTextField1.setText("Press to minimize");
}                                   

private void jButton5MouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
    jTextField1.setText("Need help ? ");
}
```

What i should to with the text field 1 so that i can meet my requirements ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is how you should do it :

```
private void jButtonMouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    jTextField.setText("Mouse Entered to your Button...");
}                                     

private void jButtonMouseExited(MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    jTextField.setText("");
}
```